# Fixing various problems with attic insulation

Tags: insulation, attic

I have a 22 year old home that has various insulation problems in the attic. Here's a quick rundown of the types of problems I'm seeing, numbered for reference:

1. Gaps at the top edges of wall insulation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. Gaps underneath the edge of our cathedral ceiling:

[image]

3. Gaps where pipes block part of a wall cavity:

[image]

4. Gaps around outlets:

[image]

5. Areas where the ceiling height changes. In the attic, these look like popups with blown in insulation on top. The problem is that the insulation tends to fall off on the edges, leaving little coverage there:

[image]

[image]

[image]

6. Similar to problem #5, we also have tray ceiling popups where insulation tends to fall off on the sides (here includes an inside shot of the tray ceiling):

[image]

[image]

[image]

For problems 1, 2, 3 and 4, what's the best fix? Spray foam? Stuff more bat insulation in the gaps?

For problems 5 and 6, and ideas for keeping the blow in insulation in place around the edges of raised ceilings?

Input appreciated!